# Is this formula $\Sigma_1^{ZF}$?

Tags: logic, set-theory

This is probably a simple question.

Let $\varphi(x)$ be a formula expressing $dom(x)\not\in Ord$.  I want to know whether $\varphi$ is a $\Sigma_1^{ZF}$ formula or not, meaning whether there is a $\Sigma_1$ formula $\psi(x)$ so that $ZF$ proves $\forall x (\varphi(x)\leftrightarrow \psi(x))$.

($\varphi$ is just an example I came up with trying to understand why the recursion used to define "$x=L_{\alpha}$" is $\Sigma_1^{ZF}$)

I would write $\varphi(x) \leftrightarrow (\exists y\, (y\not\in Ord \land (\forall z \ ( z\in y \leftrightarrow z\in dom(x)))))$,

where $z\in dom(x)$ can be replaced by a certain $\Sigma_0$ formula.

So does this mean that $\varphi$ is not $\Sigma_1^{ZF}$ or can the $\forall$-quantor be eliminated? Especially, does that mean that the formula $a=t(b)$ is not in general $\Sigma_1^{ZF}$ (a,b variables) if $t$ is a term so that the formula expressing membership in $t(b)$, $z\in t(b)$, is $\Sigma_0^{ZF}$ ? You can see I am a bit confused.. [edit: This is apparently true : $a=P(b)$ is not $\Sigma_1^{ZF}$ (P denoting powerset), but $z\in P(b)$ is $\Sigma_0$]

Comment: What's wrong with $\exists{y} (y \in \mathrm{dom}(x) \wedge y \not\in On)$? Since if $\mathrm{dom}(x)$ is not an ordinal then it has a member which is not an ordinal.

Comment: @BenedictEastaugh: It can be the case that the domain of $x$ contains only ordinals but it isn't an ordinal. For example $\omega\setminus 5$ contains only ordinals but it is not an ordinal.

Comment: @Apostolos of course, silly of me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula $y\subseteq\mathrm{dom}(x)$ is $\Delta_0$. This is because it is written as: $$(\forall z\in y)(\exists w\in x)[ w\textrm{ is a pair }\land(\exists u\in w)(x\in u\land(\forall v\in u)(v=x))].$$ Likewise the formula $\mathrm{dom}(x)\subseteq y$ is $\Delta_0$: $$(\forall z\in x)(\exists u\in y)(\{u\}\in z).$$

Hence $y=\mathrm{dom}(x)$ is $\Delta_0$. Now it's easy to see that your formula is $\Sigma_1$: $$(\exists y)(y=\mathrm{dom}(x)\land y\notin On)$$ and $\Pi_1$: $$(\forall y)(y=\mathrm{dom}(x)\to y\notin On)$$ and hence it is $\Delta_1$.

Maybe it's simpler but it's late and I'm tired. I may edit this later.